# how to get the value from a nested PHP array

Tags: php

I have this php array. 
how can I get the DATA value, when I only have the TAG value?
For example, when my input is Peter, I want to return happy123, and when my input is Sam, I want to return dog11111

```
array(72) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["TAG"]=>
    string(5) "Peter"
    ["DATA"]=>
    string(8) "happy123"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["TAG"]=>
    string(3) "Sam"
    ["DATA"]=>
    string(8) "dog11111"
  }...
```

Comment: [What you have tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: You loop through the array

Comment: Possible duplicate of a million questions in the Related section to the bottom right of this page.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to loop through the array and search for the matching `TAG`:

```
function getDataByTag($arr, $tag){
    foreach($arr as $data){
        if($data['TAG'] == $tag)
            return $data['DATA'];
    }
}
```

### Demo